# Error when trying to install Sitecore using SIM - "Service WAS was not found on computer"

Tags: installation, sim

I'm currently trying to install `Sitecore 8.1 rev. 160519` using `SIM Tool 1.4.0.92 rev 150618` and I'm getting this error message in the logs:

```
>    1 12:48:04,739 ERROR Service WAS was not found on computer '.'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Service WAS was not found on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as an installed service
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateNames()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_ServiceName()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GenerateStatus()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.get_Status()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.GetServiceStatus(String serviceName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.get_State()
   at SIM.Adapters.WebServer.Website.get_ApplicationPoolState()
   at SIM.Tool.Base.InstanceHelperEx.EnsureAppPoolState(Instance instance, Window mainWindow)
   at SIM.Tool.Base.InstanceHelperEx.PreheatInstance(Instance instance, Window mainWindow, Boolean ignoreAdvancedSetting)
   at SIM.Tool.Base.AuthenticationHelper.LoginAsAdmin(Instance instance, Window owner, String pageUrl, String browser)
   at SIM.Tool.Windows.MainWindowComponents.LoginAdminButton.OnClick(Window mainWindow, Instance instance)
   at SIM.Tool.Windows.MainWindowHelper.c__DisplayClass2d.b__25(Object param0, RoutedEventArgs param1)
```

The other symptom is that IIS refuses to start my site.

This is occurring on a `Windows Server 2012 R2` machine.

Has anyone encountered this message before?

Comment: Have you checked this one http://serverfault.com/questions/384237/service-was-was-not-found-on-computer ?

Comment: Have you tried run as administrator? And if you have .NET Framework 3.5 installed?

Comment: @Marek is right; this question is asked and answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/384237/service-was-was-not-found-on-computer

Comment: @Marek you were right ^^

I was indeed missing Window Process Activation Service >> Process Model on my Windows 2012 machine.

Thanks to you, I was able to solved my problem :D

Comment: @Frederic you're welcome. I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing Windows Process Activation Service on your computer.

Check `Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Windows Process Activation Service`.

More details here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/384237/service-was-was-not-found-on-computer